# Send Relationship Error when creating sendable data extension with SubscriberID

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I'm trying to create a sendable data extension, but keep getting the following error: "Error: Subscriber ID must be related to a field with a Number Data Type."

The steps I take when creating the data extension are:

- Create Standard Data Extension
- Check "Is Sendable" Box
- Add a field named "SubscriberID"
- Select *Number* for Data Type
- For the Send Relationship I select *SubscriberID* relates to Subscribers on *Subscriber ID*

When I try to hit the Create button, I get that error message noted above. Will Salesforce not allow you to send to a data extension using just SubscriberID as the identifier for the subscriber? Seems like you should be able to since they have Subscriber ID as an option in the second Send Relationship dropdown.

Comment: What is the data type for your subscriber id column in your data extension?

Comment: SubscriberID is a number so your field must be of data type number

Comment: I selected _Number_ as the Data Type for the SubscriberID field I created, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: I just ran a test and couldn't replicate the issue (it let me use SubscriberID field - in fact, it doesn't even let me select a field that isn't a number). If everyone you've stated is true, I would open a case with support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the field name.
Below is the screenshot attached with the details.
[image]